# How do I make so an image goes over a div container?

Tags: css

I encountered this problem when I was fixing my footer. Before it worked perfectly fine.

This is the code:[image]

```css
.light {
    position: absolute;
    top: 97.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

FOOTER:

```css
.contacts {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(14, 14, 14);
    margin-top: 10rem;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;    
}
```

I didn't try anything else, because I just couldn't understand how to get out of this problem

Before I did anything to the footer it worked perfectly fine, but after I fixed the footer, the light wasn't going over the footer. The code I'm using now for the footer(doesn't work)

```css
width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
```

The code I used before, when it worked: position: absolute;`

Comment: did you check the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSREF/pr_pos_z-index.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the element you want above your footer, you want to give it a `z-index` tag, and for the element you want layered behind you, you want to give it a lower `z-index` number,

for example:

```css
.light {
    position: absolute;
    top: 97.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
.contacts {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(14, 14, 14);
    margin-top: 10rem;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;    
    z-index: 0;
}
```